# Configure AWS credentials to work with both the CLI and SDKs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

In trying to automate some deploy tasks to S3, I noticed that the credentials I provided via `aws configure` are not picked up by the Node.js SDK. How can I get the shell and a gulp task to reference the same file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After lots of searching, it was the excerpt from [this article](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx3D6U6WSFGOK2H/A-New-and-Standardized-Way-to-Manage-Credentials-in-the-AWS-SDKs) that caused a eureka moment.

> If you've been using the AWS CLI, you might already have a credentials
>   file, which is in the same location as the new credentials file, but
>   is named `config`. If so, the CLI will continue to use that file.
>   However, if you create a new credentials file, the CLI will use that
>   one instead. (Be aware that the `aws configure` command that you can
>   use to set credentials from the command line will put the credentials
>   in the `config` file, not the credentials file.)

By moving ~/.aws/config to ~/.aws/credentials now both the CLI and SDK read from the same location. Sadly, I haven't found any interface for maintaining ~/.aws/credentials other than hand-editing just yet.

Comment: You can mark this an the answer, looks like a solution.

Comment: @clay waiting the required 48 hours to do so. :)